# NavigationLink View Parameter SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

When I call NavigationImageView in my View , I want to send different View in every call , so I can navigate different views.But the problem is how can I send View parameter in NavigationLink. I tried View and UIView but it gives me error.

```
struct NavigationImageView: View {
    
    var item : Store
    var destinationView: View
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationLink(destination:destinationView ) {
            
            Image(uiImage: (item.banner?.url)!.load())
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(CGFloat((item.banner?.ratio)!), contentMode: .fit)
                .cornerRadius(12)
                .shadow(radius: 4)
                .frame(width: CGFloat(UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.9), height: CGFloat((UIScreen.main.bounds.width / CGFloat((item.banner?.ratio) ?? 1))))
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use generics here, because type of destination view is not known in advance:

```
struct NavigationImageView<DestinationType: View>: View {
    
    var item : Store
    var destinationView: DestinationType

    // ... other code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the following example...

Your property has to be `any View` and then you can assign any View to it which you will use as your destination.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var showViewTwo : Bool = false
    
    //computed property of type some View which returns different views depending on a condition
    var destination : some View { 
        if showViewTwo {
            return Text("Hello Second View")
        }
        else
        {
            return Text("Hello First View")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
           NavigationLink("Press me", destination: destination)
        }
        
        Button(action: {
            showViewTwo.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Toggle View")
        }
        
    }
}
```